# WCF for SP Developer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wcf

AS a SharePoint developer, how common is it to use and work with windows communication foundation? What context? Any real based example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create WCF web services for integration with other applications. A real world example is a custom .net web application we had that communicated with the SharePoint server to add documents, create new SharePoint sites, change permissions to the SharePoint site etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have create a customized, independent and separated .net application that is acting with the same functionality in SP:s administration?

Comment: The "customized, independent and separated .net application" already had some functionality including permissions handling, creation of documents etc. The WCF services handled automation of transfer of permissions and documents to the SharePoint site. So the .net application in that sence acted as administration of the SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create wcf services to handle special purpose tasks (store data outside of sharepoint, aggregate data). Or when in the case of SP2010 when the application runs in .net 4 runtime and I need to bridge.

Comment: "need to bridge"?

Comment: SP2010 cant run .net 4 assemblies. If you still want to use it you need a "wcf runtime bridge" ;)